# Creating user story under particular feature in Rally using rally test API

Tags: rally

How to map newly created user story to Feature and that feature to Capability using rally rest api

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the following way using pyral and python:

```
from pyral import Rally

SERVER = 'SERVER'
USER = 'USER'
PASSWORD = 'PASSWORD'
WORKSPACE = 'WORKSPACE'
PROJECT = 'PROJECT'
TARGET_FEATURES = ['F123']
TARGET_USEREMAIL = "123@gmail.com"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rally = Rally(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, workspace=WORKSPACE, project=PROJECT)

    user_req = rally.get('User', fetch=True, query='EmailAddress = "%s"' % TARGET_USEREMAIL)
    user = us_req.next()

    for feature in TARGET_FEATURES:
        f_req = rally.get('Feature', fetch=True, query='FormattedID = %s' % feature)
        f = f_req.next()

        feature_update = {
                "ObjectID": f.oid,
                "User": user.ref
        }

        try:
            update_feature = rally.update('Feature', feature_update)
            print "=> %s has been updated." % (f.FormattedID)
        except:
            print "=> Failed to update %s." % (f.FormattedID)
```